# R - How to create a list with an unknown variable name

Tags: r

I need to create a list like this:

```
{globalKey1="x",globalKey2="y",globalKey3="z"...}
```

I know the right name of the global keys only a run-time:

```
assign(paste(x[1,]$globalKey,dim,sep=""),ARIMA)
```

Now i need to add this key to a list:

```
arimaList<-c(arimaList, paste(x[1,]$globalKey,dim,sep=""))
```

The previous code create:

```
{"x","y","z"}
```

If i try:

```
arimaList<-c(arimaList, paste(x[1,]$globalKey,dim,sep="")=paste(x[1,]$globalKey,dim,sep=""))
```

doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

-----Mod-15/02-----

Thanks to all.

This is a working example to make {"ab"=val}

```
assign(paste("a","b",sep=""),"val")
arimaList<<-list();
arimaList<<-c(arimaList, get(paste("a","b",sep=""))
names(arimaList)[length(arimaList)]<-paste("a","c",sep="")
```

Comment: Your life will be much simpler if you learn to use the `names()` function to simply set the names of objects, rather than using `assign`. Hard to say much more without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
arimaList <- list("x", "y", "z")
unknown.name <- "GlobalKey"
names(arimaList) <- paste0(unknown.name, 1:length(arimaList))
arimaList
# $GlobalKey1
# [1] "x"
# 
# $GlobalKey2
# [1] "y"
# 
# $GlobalKey3
# [1] "z"
```